# New Line in Python not working

Tags: python

I have to read from one file and input it to another file alphabetized. So I did the strip and then sorted() and now I can not get it to new line for some reason Can some one please guide me on what i am doing incorrect.

```
      infile = open("unsorted_fruits.txt", "r")
      outfile=open("sorted_fruits.txt","w")



      for line in infile:
          fruit=infile.read().split() 
          fruits = sorted(fruit)
          timeflies = str(fruits)
          outfile.write(timeflies + '\n');
          print (timeflies )



      infile.close()
      outfile.close()
```

Comment: ... *how is it not working*?

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct?  It looks like you are doing all of the steps for every line in the input file.

Comment: In any event... your error is here: `fruit=infile.read().split()`

Comment: It does not print in a newline to console or to file . I have no idea why. I have been researching it and the file it prints it out n aphabetical order but it is going across the screen instead of one word per line

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I do not understand, I read here on stack that to alphabetize it and use sort I had to do that first.

Comment: That's because you read the entire file on the first iteration, `infile.read`, making your for-loop only one iteration long. Then, you write it out as a big string wiht a single newline at the end.

Comment: Yes, but not *inside a for loop over the `infile`

Comment: How many fruits per line?

Comment: If one fruit per line: `for line in sorted(infile):outfile.write(line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did wrong: you have read everything from `infile` at `infile.read()` during the first iteration, but for the second iteration, there's nothing left to read. So you should read the file before the loop and iterate through the sorted list.

Try this:

```
infile = open("unsorted_fruits.txt", "r")
outfile=open("sorted_fruits.txt","w")

fruit=infile.read().split() 
fruits = sorted(fruit)
for line in fruits:
    timeflies = str(line)
    outfile.write(timeflies)
    print (timeflies )
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Note: `.split()` splits at every white space, **not** every new line. So if you have spaces in your fruit name, it *will* get split.

You can check out this improved version of your code:

```
with open("unsorted_fruits.txt", "r") as infile, 
        open("sorted_fruits.txt","w") as outfile:
    fruits = sorted(infile.readlines())
    outfile.writelines(fruits)
```

Comment: This works perfectly,  not quite sure what i messed up still I mean I see where i messed it up but don't understand it. thank you very much btw.

Comment: @jadsq there, I explained :)

Answer (score 0):

You were writing the array itself.  Here is a modified version that works.

```
infile = open("unsorted_fruits.txt", "r")
outfile=open("sorted_fruits.txt","w")

fruit=infile.read().split()

fruits = sorted(fruit)
timeflies = str(fruits)
print (timeflies )

for fruit in fruits:
    outfile.write(fruit + '\n')

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANALYSIS:**

Here's what your loop does, line by line:

```
# Reading each line of input:
for line in infile:

    # Ignore that first line and read
    #   the rest of the file.
    #   Split that into individual fruit names
    fruit=infile.read().split()

    # Sort the list of fruits #2 through end-of-file
    fruits = sorted(fruit)

    # Make a string representation of that list.
    timeflies = str(fruits)

    # Put a single line feed after that string and dump it
    #   to the output file.
    outfile.write(timeflies + '\n');
    print (timeflies)
```

Just to make the point clear, `timeflies` is a string that looks like this:

```
"['apple', 'kumquat', 'persimmon', 'pineapple', 'tomato']"
```

It's not a list; it's a string that looks like the list you might want to use next.  Perhaps a useful next step would have been

```
timeflies = '\n'.join(fruits)
```

However, you still wasted your loop (it can execute only once) and lost the first line.  Do you see how that (failed to) work?

**SOLUTION:**

```
infile = open("unsorted_fruits.txt", "r")
outfile=open("sorted_fruits.txt","w")

# Make a list of the input fruits
fruit_list = []
for line in infile:
    fruit_list.extend(line.split())

# Sort that list
fruit_list.sort()

# Print it to the output file, one line at a time
for fruit in fruit_list:
    print(fruit, file=outfile)
```

Input file:

```
banana
pineapple
tomato
kumquat
apple
persimmon
```

Output file:

```
$ cat sorted_fruits.txt 
apple
banana
kumquat
persimmon
pineapple
tomato
```